# Get Artist art from MediaStore

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the artist art from the MediaStore? I know how to retrieve the album art, but cannot figure out how to get the Artist Art.

I know this can be done because there are quite a few Music Player out there that display it like this one here - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kodarkooperativet.blackplayerfree

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the artist art is retrieved from the internet and not from the MediaStore.

Comment: Would you know how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the Artist art directly from the MediaStore. Popular apps like **[MusixMatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify)** uses their own image database to search and fetch the artist art.

However you can use the following tricks,

1. Use Google Image Search API (deprecated)

Get the artist name from the MediaStore and search using the name as a keyword,

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=your_artist_name

```
{
    GsearchResultClass: "GimageSearch",
    width: "1024",
    height: "768",
    imageId: "ANd9GcSD3JQPsOIOFjvOixqoSFlDC161zKJW_rdSzKic4NVALbMVxcej7uOyXec",
    tbWidth: "150",
    tbHeight: "113",
    unescapedUrl: "http://themetalreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/opeth.jpg",
    url: "http://themetalreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/opeth.jpg",
    visibleUrl: "themetalreview.com",
    title: "<b>Opeth</b> @ The Astor Theatre, Perth | The Metal Review",
    titleNoFormatting: "Opeth @ The Astor Theatre, Perth | The Metal Review",
    originalContextUrl: "http://themetalreview.com/opeth-the-astor-theatre-perth/",
    content: "<b>opeth</b>",
    contentNoFormatting: "opeth",
    tbUrl: "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSD3JQPsOIOFjvOixqoSFlDC161zKJW_rdSzKic4NVALbMVxcej7uOyXec"
    }
```

and it'll reponse with all the possilbe matches and image url in JSON format. Later parse the response and show in your player.

2. Use Google Custom Search API (limited search for free version)

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

3. Use TinEye Image API

https://services.tineye.com/developers/tineyeapi/overview.html#get-request

4. Make your own database and a API service to request and fetch image.

There are so many sources out there in the internet to search and get the Image URL. You can give it a try.

Hope that'll help.